Movie from Theatre of Tragedy song
Is text in the song And When He Falleth by Theatre of Tragedy from a movie? If that's a movie what is the title?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HttMkyho2lg

That is Vincent Price speaking in The Masque of the Red Death, (1964).  From IMDB's quote page for the movie:

Prospero: That cross you wear around your neck; is it only a
  decoration, or are you a true Christian believer?
Francesca: Yes, I believe - truly.
Prospero: Then I want you to remove it at once! And never to wear it
  within this castle again!
Francesca: You had me take off my cross because it offended...
Prospero: It offended no one. My Master and his followers look about
  with open eyes. No, it simply appeared to me to be discourteous... to
  wear the symbol of a deity long dead.

